# InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map, and not an instance of StreetViewPanorama

Tags: javascript, google-maps, safari

When I tested my site cross browser and tried it in Safari, This error in my Dashboard show out of nowhere. It's working in Chrome, Firefox and IE9 but in Safari:

This is the error and i dont know where this takes place

```
InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map, and not an instance of StreetViewPanorama     main:25
```

and this is the Initialize function:

```
var map;

    function initialize() {

        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocode = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        LatLang = new google.maps.LatLng(38.50, -90.50);
        var addresse = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: LatLang,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), addresse);

        // Bounds for North America
        var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                  new google.maps.LatLng(15.70, -160.50),
                  new google.maps.LatLng(68.85, -55.90));

        // Listen for the dragend event
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function () {
            if (strictBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) return;
            // We're out of bounds - Move the map back within the bounds

            var c = map.getCenter(),
                  x = c.lng(),
                  y = c.lat(),
                  maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
                  maxY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
                  minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
                  minY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

            if (x < minX) x = minX;
            if (x > maxX) x = maxX;
            if (y < minY) y = minY;
            if (y > maxY) y = maxY;

            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(y, x));
        });

        // Limit the zoom level
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
            if (map.getZoom() < minZoomLevel) map.setZoom(minZoomLevel);
        });

    }
```

Comment: It would help to know which line of your code is causing this exception, i.e. the line that calls into the Maps library and encounters this situation.  Step through your code line by line in a debugger until the exception happens, or turn on Break On Unhandled Exceptions (e.g. in Chrome Dev Tools) to trap the exception occurring and then hunt up the stack trace back to your code to identify the last line of your code that ran well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand few of safaris, and javascripts quark to solve this.

```
var t = 5;
var t
console.log(t) //undefined in chrome, firefox, etc. But 5 in safari.
```

You should also know that in new html5 spec if you have something like `<div id="map"></div>`, this creates a global variable `map` or `window.map`

In your code I see you have `map` defined as a global variable (might be there for debugging).

If this script runs after the `<body>...</body>` is rendered which contained your `<div id="map"></div>`, `window.map` or(global `map`) get initialized as `"<div id="map"></div>"`, and when you again declare `var map`, `map` becomes `<div id="map"></div>` in safari and `undefined` in rest of the browsers.

This is the cause of error. To fix this, either change the id to something else other that `map`, or do `var map = "";` when you declare this as global variable. Or, run the script before the body.